# JQuery Nested Sortable and Javascript

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Hello I am working on a JQuery nested sortable lists, I came across a plugin for nested sorting [here](https://github.com/mjsarfatti/nestedSortable/blob/master/jquery.mjs.nestedSortable.js)
I can drag and drop the list items successfully but I want to have an ajax call once an item in the list is dragged, Is it possible to this with this plugin ? Does it provide any option to call ajax after the drag is complete?

My JS file is

```
$('#sortable').nestedSortable(
   {
        disableNesting: 'no-nest',
        forcePlaceholderSize: true,
        handle: 'div',
        items: 'li',
        opacity: .6,
        placeholder: 'placeholder',
        revert: 250,
        tabSize: 25,
        tolerance: 'pointer',
        toleranceElement: '> div',
        connectWith: '.sortable',
            onChange: function(serialized) {
            },
            onStop : function(){
                var element_id = $(this).attr("id");
                var parent_id = $(this).parent().attr("id");
                var prev_sibling_id = $(this).prev().attr("id");
                if(parent_id=='trash'){
                    var url = $(this).attr("patent-trash");
                    var data = {PID:element_id};
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        data: data,
                        url:url,
                        cache: false,
                        success: function(data) {
                            document.location.reload(true);
                        }
                    });
                }
 });
```

I used onStop before which worked but there were some issues, I think the plugin is same but some updates are done 1 month ago, Is it now giving any option for calling ajax after the drag is complete or is there any alternative way to do it?

Please help me I tried all my efforts

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution :) Since it is connect with jQuery Sortable so all the events, options and methods are available here. I used

```
  stop:function(){
  var element_id = $(this).attr("id");
            var parent_id = $(this).parent().attr("id");
            var prev_sibling_id = $(this).prev().attr("id");
            if(parent_id=='trash'){
                var url = $(this).attr("patent-trash");
                var data = {PID:element_id};
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    data: data,
                    url:url,
                    cache: false,
                    success: function(data) {
                        document.location.reload(true);
                    }
                });
            }

  }
```

and it worked :)